# Unable to display text overlay using css

Tags: html, css

I think I am close, but I don't know what am missing.
I am using the same code as is on this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2tPGy/3/

HTML:

```
    <ul class="projectGrid align">
        <li id="project-1">
             <a href="#">
                 <div class="img-overlay">
                     <h4>Title</h4>
                     <p>A description of the image</p>
                 </div>
             </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

CSS:

```
  .projectGrid li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 20px 20px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 opacity:0.7;
 border-radius: 11px;
 -moz-border-radius: 11px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 11px;

 text-indent: -9000px;
-webkit-transition: box-shadow .25s  ease-in-out, opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: box-shadow .25s  ease-in-out, opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: box-shadow .25s  ease-in-out, opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: box-shadow .25s  ease-in-out, opacity .25s ease-in-out;
 transition: box-shadow .25s  ease-in-out, opacity .25s ease-in-out;

 }  
   .projectGrid li a {
   display: block;
   width: 280px;
   height: 280px;
   background-color: grey;
   border: solid;
   border-radius: 11px;
  -moz-border-radius: 11px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 11px;
  } .projectGrid li:hover {
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
   opacity:1.0;

  }
 #project-1 {
    height:286px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    width:286px;
 }
.img-overlay {
    background-color:#000;
    bottom:0;
    color:#fff;
    opacity:0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    z-index:1000;
}
#project-1:hover .img-overlay {
    opacity:0.75;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
    transition:opacity 0.25s;
    -moz-transition:opacity 0.25s;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.25s;
}
#project-1 a {
    background: url('../images/1.png') no-repeat scroll;
    background-size: 280px 280px;
}
```

The code works on the fiddle, but does not work on my website.
The text in the div does not show up on my website.
Can anyone guide me as to why this might be happening?

Comment: "The code works on the fiddle, but does not work on my website." Then what's the point of the jsFiddle? Put the relevant code here please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [my fork of your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/vRQP2/).  Is this what you're looking for? Basically, instead of making adjustments to the opacity, use `display:none` on the regular `.img-overlay` css, then change to `display:block` on `:hover`.  Does this work on your site? I also made @Giacomo1968's suggested edits regarding your unclosed `ui` tag, assuming you meant `ul`.

Also, why is this line in here?

```
text-indent:-9000px;
```

I commented that out and everything looks great in the [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/H4pKe/). Let me know if that fixes things on your end.

Comment: I reformatted the code.I hope its easier to read.And yes the ul tag i forgot to copy, but its there on my site.The issue I am having is that the text in the div does not show up, but the overlay does.Is that clearer?

Comment: Oh wow, that was not at all what I thought you were saying. I'll look at it again.

Comment: Did you remove the two opacity lines from the main `.img-overlay` css like @JakeGould said?

Comment: @Austin:I just saw that too and I think it was old code from previous attempts at something else.The text indent was the issue.I removed that and it works.Thank you!.

Answer (score 2):

Not only is the `<ul>` tag misspelled as `<ui>` but the `<ul>` wasn't closed. jsFiddle update here: http://jsfiddle.net/KwyDt/3/

```
<ul class="blah">
  <li id="project-1">
      <a href="#">
      <div class="img-overlay">
          <h4>Title</h4>
          <p>A description of the image</p>
      </div>
      </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Also that `<a href="#"></a>` wrapping around a `<div>` is completely wrong. Was going to debug the CSS more but you might need to clarify what the final result is. As it stands this is really messy & hard to decipher. I think it works now, but I am still not sure based on the way the code is formatted.